# how to make my slider continue its loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider build up from a list `ul` contains 15 `li`.

I show each `5` elements as a group. In the and if you click next or previous buttons it will move slowly to the next five elements but after the third click (when you click previous for the forth time) it is not showing any elements.
I know that is normal because I use `right: "+=855"` to move the elements so after three movements the 15 elements will ends .

I want this loop to continue (on the forth click I want to show the elements from the elements 1-5).

This link will show what I mean :
http://jsfiddle.net/mpx83tpv/1/

Is there any addition to the `animate` function that I could add to achieve this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the slider to wrap around to the first element, like a ring. From the fiddle you linked to, it seems like this isn't possible with your code. However, if you change your code to show specific slides instead, you can adjust it to show the first ones after the last ones, with an `if` statement to make sure the number wraps around to zero instead of overflowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no addition to animate that could do such thing, but you always can use `.prepend()` or `.append()` like:

```
$("ul.slider").animate({
    right: "+=855"
}, 1000, function(){
    $("ul.slider").css('right', '0');
    $('ul.slider li:not(:nth-child(n+6))').appendTo('ul.slider');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpx83tpv/3/)

Comment: I want to thank u it works like a charm . but I want you to explain me the `n` please what does `n` stand for?

Comment: @BaselShbeb If you r talkin bout the `n` in `nth-child(n+6)`, that is the standart syntax of nth child

Answer (score 0):

Just shuffle the `<li>`s to the end after the scrolling:

```
$(".prev_button").click(function () {
    $("ul.slider").animate({
        right: "+=855"
    }, 5000, function () {
        $("ul.slider").append($("ul.slider li:lt(5)"))
            .css("right", "-=855");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mpx83tpv/9/